# Assigning each identical list item a value

Tags: python

The function I'm writing has a list of lists. I would like to loop through the list, take the first element and all matching elements in the list, and assign 0 in another array in the same positions. Then for 1, and so on until all the elements are assigned.

How do I do this in python?

Take this list:

```
[[0.39999999999999997],
 [2.145454545454545],
 [0.39999999999999997],
 [0.39999999999999997],
 [0.39999999999999997],
 [2.145454545454545],
 [2.145454545454545],
 [2.145454545454545],
 [2.145454545454545],
 [2.145454545454545],
 [2.145454545454545],
 [2.145454545454545],
 [0.39999999999999997],
 [0.39999999999999997],
 [0.39999999999999997],
 [2.145454545454545],
 [2.145454545454545],
 [2.145454545454545]]
```

And output `[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]`

Or

```
closestCluster labels:

 [[0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28],
[0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42,
 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.3
2, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0
.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28],
[0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42,
 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.3
2, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0
.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28],
[0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42,
 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.3
2, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0
.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28], [0.18, 0.31, 0.32, 0.42, 0.28],
[0.18, 0.34, 0.71, 0.71, 0.9]]
```

Into a similar list. I would like this to work for R^n, but for 1 to 4 is my test data.

Comment: Can you show an example instead of trying to explain in words?

Comment: Take this list: [[0.39999999999999997], [2.145454545454545], [0.39999999999999997], [0.39999999999999997], [0.399
99999999999997], [2.145454545454545], [2.145454545454545], [2.145454545454545], [2.145454545454545], [2.145454545454545]
, [2.145454545454545], [2.145454545454545], [0.39999999999999997], [0.39999999999999997], [0.39999999999999997], [2.1454
54545454545], [2.145454545454545], [2.145454545454545]] And output [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]

Comment: Please edit your post with that information. All formatting is lost if you paste it into the comment area.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do:

```
lst = ["A","A","B","C","A"]
values = {}

i = 0
for value in lst:
    if value[0] in values: continue
    values[value[0]] = i
    i += 1

lst2 = [values[n[0]] for n in lst]
```

Output:

```
>>> print(lst2)
[0, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

* edited as per OP's edit

Comment: This works for the 1 dimension data I posted, but is there a way to generalize to n dimensions? I've written a k-means clustering algorithm (for a class), which outputs the clusters assigned to the position of the matching input vector.

Comment: @khaannn It's super unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. You really need to provide a set of expected outputs for your inputs. What have you tried so far? Are you expecting `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]` to return `[0,0]` or `[[0,1,2], [0,1,2]]` and etc?